# How to resolve this import error in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, namespace-package

I have a [very simple namespace package](https://github.com/korommatyi/import-error-repro) (contents included below, as well as the directory layout). If I try to import `namespace_repro.module`, I got the following error: `AttributeError: module 'namespace_repro' has no attribute 'module'`. As far as I understand my package has a valid layout and the import should work. Interestingly, the error is present only in Python 3.6.8 and the import succeeds in Python 3.7.

### How to reproduce the problem?

I have a directory named `import-error-repro` with in it a `setup.py` (see below), then a nested directory path `src/namespace_repro/module`, containing three files, `__init__.py`, `x.py` and `y.py`. Their contents:

`setup.py`

```
from setuptools import find_namespace_packages, setup

setup(
    name='namespace-repro',
    version='0.1.0',
    python_requires='>=3.6',
    packages=find_namespace_packages('src'),
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

`src/namespace_repro/module/__init__.py`:

```
from namespace_repro.module.x import x
```

`src/namespace_repro/module/x.py`:

```
import namespace_repro.module.y as y

x = y.y
```

and finally `src/namespace_repro/module/y.py`:

```
y = True
```

I created a brand new Python 3.6 conda environment by `conda create -n namespace6 python=3.6 ipython`, then I activated it and installed the package as `pip install -e ./import-error-repro` (note that `-e` doesn't matter, the problem is reproducible without it). After that, I tried  `import namespace_repro.module` in `ipython` (though the same happens in the official python interpreter). The result is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-bcae5a697dad> in <module>
----> 1 import namespace_repro.module

~/namespace-repro/src/namespace_repro/module/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from namespace_repro.module.x import x

~/namespace-repro/src/namespace_repro/module/x.py in <module>
----> 1 import namespace_repro.module.y as y
      2 
      3 x = y.y

AttributeError: module 'namespace_repro' has no attribute 'module'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The strange thing is that the import system finds `namespace_repro.module` twice but fails at the third time!

Some other interesting behaviour:

```
In [1]: import namespace_repro.module.y as y  # This doesn't work.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-4035347ea59b> in <module>
----> 1 import namespace_repro.module.y as y

AttributeError: module 'namespace_repro' has no attribute 'module'

In [2]: import namespace_repro.module.y  # But this one does! Why?

In [3]: dir(namespace_repro.module.y) # The error returns when we actually want to use the module.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d89bcfd9e509> in <module>
----> 1 dir(namespace_repro.module.y)

AttributeError: module 'namespace_repro' has no attribute 'module'

In [4]: from namespace_repro.module.y import y  # This works fine!

In [5]: y
Out[5]: True
```

### Directory layout

```
. import-error-repro
+-- setup.py
+-- src
|   +-- namespace_repro
|   |   +-- module
|   |   |   +-- __init__.py
|   |   |   +-- x.py
|   |   |   +-- y.py
```

Comment: I have the same problem. This kind of import problem happens only on python 3.6.x . Same code working on 3.7, fails in any 3.6 version. Nobody know what is going on here with the version?

Comment: You're right, I didn't know that worked. I don't know your problem.

Comment: code in module/* is wrong, so it never gets imported and attribute module is not created in namespace. use from . import y and from .  import x and import will succeed

Comment: This is [issue #30024](https://bugs.python.org/issue30024), fixed in Python 3.7.0. See the duplicate as well, which also covers this in detail. The work-around is to use `import namespace_repro.module.y`, then `y = namespace_repro.module.y`, or use `from namespace_repro.module import y`.

Comment: What happens is that `sys.modules['namespace_repro']` and `sys.modules['namespace_repro.module']` are still in the 'importing' state, and don't yet have the requisite attributes set (there is no `sys.modules['namespace_repro'].module` yet because `sys.modules['namespace_repro.module']` is still being processed), but the `import ... as ...` machinery relies on those attributes having been set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is CPython bug [30024](https://bugs.python.org/issue30024), which unsurprisingly was fixed in 3.7.  Note that the more idiomatic form with relative (circular) imports has worked since 3.5.

Comment: Yes, which is why I closed this as a duplicate. You got in just under the wire, but the bounty is gone, sorry.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Not a problem.  This seemed obscure enough that I didn’t even think to look for a duplicate.